# Adding Font Awesome to webpage

Tags: icons

I would like some help adding font awesome icons to a webpage. The kit is part of the websites by default, so I need to figure out the syntax.

Here is a tiny bit of the code for one icon:

```html
<li><a href="https://artesiafire.colorado.gov/" target="_self"><img alt="image not found" src="https://townofdinosaur.colorado.gov/sites/townofdinosaur/files/Fire%20Hydrant.png" /><span>Artesia Volunteer Fire</span> </a></li>
```

This is some widget code I found on the internet, it make cool icon type buttons: https://townofdinosaur.colorado.gov/business-directory

This is what needs to be inserted to replace the icon I'm using... `html <i class="fa-solid fa-fire-hydrant"></i>`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the fire hydrant icon from Font-awesome, correct?

Remember this icon is from the **Pro** version. If you are using the free version isn't gonna work.

Download the assets and put on the folders

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./fontawesome/css/all.min.css">
```

Just put it on your body

```
<i class="fa-solid fa-fire-hydrant"></i>
```